# User defined domain masking sub domain

Tags: apache-2.2

I am looking to build a site where users have their own pages on 'username.mywebsite.com'. I am able to do this easily with htaccess in Apache but I was wondering:

How can I make it so that the user can set it up to use their own domain? So instead of username.mysite.com, when the user went to userswebsite.com it would show their page on my site?

I have done some research and I think it can be done with CNAMEs but I'm not sure about how they work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume that you are using rewrite rules in htaccess? You are going to at the very least have to have a virtual host entry for each domain other than mywebsite.com.

Comment: Is there a way that this can be done automatically rather than manually? I would be using PHP. I am at the planning stage at the project right now or I'd post more info.

Comment: Anything is possible. :) It sounds like you are heading down the road of recreating something like plesk or cpanel to me. If you want something free as in beer check out ServerPilot.

Comment: Actually trying to create a simple website hosting site for a specific online game so that users are able to make money from their servers. Albeit, it's A Minecraft donation store plugin similar to Buycraft.net. Any ideas though given the question? Or anything you would recommend I search up for ?

Comment: Plesk cpanel, and ServerPilot are all simple tools to facilitate management of a server hosting multiple websites. You can certainly write code to automate anything that you desire. Not knowing your requirements there is no way I can do anything but paint with broad strokes. I would not get too hung up on that part of your project. Writing a file into the apache conf.d is not hard to do.,. You have plenty of more challenging problems to solve I would imagine.

Comment: Honestly I'm pretty experienced with everything I'm going to be doing and I have a small team of developers working on it with me. This is actually the most challenging problem for me at the moment believe it or not, haha, but thanks; I will take a look at Plesk and ServerPilot and see if I can allow users to use their own domains to show their sub domained page on my site :) 

Comment: haha, ok all you need to do is just place a file in the apache conf.d with a virtual host for each extra domain you are going to process requests for as I indicted inititally. When you started asking about automating a simple thing like file creation it seemed you were looking for a "no-code" solution.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to make it so that I don't have to restart Apache every time a user adds a custom domain as I expect to have a lot of users on the site at any given time.

Comment: have you tried reload?

Comment: Just had a Google, that's actually a good idea. I could do that.

Comment: I was thinking it may not be super safe to execute it as soon as the user requests but I could have a script that runs every x amount of hours which checks the database for any domain virtual host files that haven't been created.

Comment: Grr keep pressing return on my iPad haha, well thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up the customer's website configuration to accept requests based on the customer's domain name (so you would need to know what it is in advance).

Then the customer points their domain name to your IP address.

You don't want to use `cname`'s for this because a `cname` at the apex of the domain indicates that there are no other records in the domain, and the rest of the customer's DNS might break, and you don't want to be responsible for that.

This means that you have to have a stable IP configuration (i.e. your IP address of your server never changes), and if you do need to change it in the future, you need to give your customers ample warning in advance about how and when to change their DNS.